# R plot: avoid showing step by step changes and only show the final plot

Tags: r, graphics, plot, jupyter-notebook

So, with R base graphics, I start a plot with command **plot()** and then I add more lines (or points, or legends) with subsequent commands. However, I want to only display the final graph, not step by step changes.

The reason is that I'm using IPython-Rkernel, and and I only want to display the final result. So, here is a link to my ipython-notebook:

http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/mirjalil/DataScience/blob/master/regressionAnalysis.ipynb#ridge-regression

So, you can see that I first plot the points, the add two lines, and then the legends, and that results in 4 graphs! But I only want to show the final graph!

I tried to save the plot in a SVG and then display that one, but is there any other way to directly disable the *display* and only display the final plot?

Comment: It would be easier to do this using more higher plot system based on the grid package ( lattice or ggplot2) where you can save your plot as an R object.

Comment: what you are describing plays very closely to the essence of `ggplot`. Is there any reason you would like to *not* use it?  Especially since it's now been ported to python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two solutions,

1: using base plotting system and **with()**:

```
with(df, {
     plot(x, y, pch=19, col=rgb(0.2, 0.4, 0.8, 0.7), cex=2, xlab="x", ylab="y", cex.axis=1.7, cex.lab=1.7);
     lines(x, predict(linear.model), col="black", lwd=6)
    })
```

2: using lattice package (based on the comments above):

```
library(lattice)

xyplot(y ~ x, df, pch=19, col=rgb(0.2, 0.4, 0.8, 0.7), cex=2,
       scales=list(cex=1.7),
       xlab=list("x", cex=1.7), ylab=list("y", cex=1.7),
       main=list("Linear Regression w. 1 Attribute", cex=1.6),
       panel = function(x,y, ...) {
            panel.xyplot(x, y, ...)
            llines(x, predict(linear.model), col="black", lwd=6)
            #llines(x, y.pred, col="black", lwd=6)
       })
```